# How to monitor the progress of Importing files?

Tags: import, monitoring

I want now,how much of percentage was imported,while importing any file.

How can I solve this?

Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: @s0rce converting into binary format, but I don't want to convert binary format. If you upload any files in gmail,It shows progress Indicator.I want to do that same visualization .so what you mention the above link is not suitable for my case.So can you reopen my question

Comment: Unless you are using low-level code to read in your data and you edit this post to show that low-level code, I say your post is not a real question. So I will not vote to reopen it.